# Symfony2 misconfigured entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I am getting two warnings about misconfigured entities in my Symfony 2 project.  It runs fine in the development environment, but the production environment will not start and I suspect these misconfigured entities might be the reason.

It is the same error on both entities so I am only including one of them as an example.

---

**BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage:**

> The field BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage#visits is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrVisit#QrImage does not contain the required 'inversedBy="visits"' attribute.

**QrVisit entity:**

```
class QrVisit 
{

...

/**
* @var object BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage
*  
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="QrImage", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $QrImage;
```

**QrImage entity:**

```
class QrImage
{

...

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrVisit", mappedBy="QrImage")
 */
private $visits;
```

I changed `QrImage` to include the `inversedBy` as below, but I probably did it wrong because I still get an error message, although a new one.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrVisit", mappedBy="QrImage", inversedBy="visits")
 */
private $visits;
```

But this generates the error:

> [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\JoinColumn declared on property BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\UserGroup::$company does not have a property named "inversedBy". Available properties: name, referencedColumnName, unique, nullable, onDelete, columnDefinition, fieldName

Comment: What do you need? Unidirectional or bi-directional relationship?

Comment: QrImage can have many QrVisits, but each QrVisit only has one QrImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to establish a bi-directional ManyToOne / OneToMany relationship you'll have to put the `mappedBy` attribute on the OneToMany side like:

`@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrVisit", mappedBy="QrImage")`

and the `inversedBy` on the ManyToOne side like:

`@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage", inversedBy="visits")`

that's all you need here. For your reference please check [Doctrine doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

The error that you're getting refers to a different entity (UserGroup) but you can check them in the same fashion.